# Validation to allow space character only when followed by an alphabet

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I am trying to validate the textbox which has to allow space character only when followed by any alphabetic character. My code fails when only a space character is inserted. What is the mistake in my code. Suggestions pls..

**javascript :**

```
function validate() {
    var firstname = document.getElementById("FirstName");
    var alpha = /^[a-zA-Z\s-, ]+$/;  
    if (firstname.value == "") {
        alert('Please enter Name');
        return false;
    }
    else if (!firstname.value.match(alpha)) {
        alert('Invalid ');       
        return false;
   }
   else 
   {
    return true;
   }
}
```

**view:**

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "searchbox" })    
 <button type="submit" onclick="return validate();">Submit</button>
```

**Conditions I applied :** 
Eg: Arun Chawla  - condition success 
Eg: _            - condition fails  (should not allow space character alone)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try following regex

```
 var alpha = /^[a-zA-Z-,]+(\s{0,1}[a-zA-Z-, ])*$/
```

First part forces an alphabetic char, and then allows space.

Comment: Thanks.It works fine for first part but doesnt allows space at the end

Comment: My bad. Samples were people names, so I assumed that you do not want spaces at the end. I've updated my answer

Comment: Bt now it is taking numeric value also.

Answer (score 0):

May be using the "test" method like this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z-,](\s{0,1}[a-zA-Z-, ])*[^\s]$/.test(firstname)
```

Only returns true when it's valid

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511938/how-to-check-for-optional-whitespace-with-regex)

I found Akiross's answer to be the best fit for me.

([a-z] ?)+[a-z]

Answer (score 0):

This will allow the space between every character,number and special character(@).

**pattern to be followed**:

```
['', [Validators.email,
        Validators.pattern('^[[\\\sa-z 0-9._%+-]+@[\\\sa-z0-9.-]+\\.[\\\sa-z]{2,4}]*$')]],
```

**output**:

`e 2 @ 2 g . c o`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/.test(name)) {
    errors['name'] = "Enter a valid name"
}
```

Comment: Please consider explanation to your code.