# Validation pattern in Yii2 form to allow alphabet, space and some symbol only

Tags: regex, validation, yii2, pattern-matching, preg-match

> > First, I've read and following suggestion from many issue/article. And this  [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263600/validation-to-allow-space-character-only-when-followed-by-an-alphabet) is the closest one. But it didn't solve my issue.

I've a text field for Job Position in my form, and I need to add validation like this:

1. Deny numeric and symbol exc: `-`, `,`, and `.`
2. Allow alphabet and space

I've add like this in modal.php

```
 'pattern' => '/^([a-z]+-)*[a-z]+$/i'
```

but It denied space, `,`, and `.`

and this is the pattern from link above:

```
'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z-,]+(\s{0,1}[a-zA-Z-, ])*$/'
```

but it didn't allowed `.`.

Maybe anyone can help me to fix the pattern above, and I wish also can give a little learn about pattern.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to restrict the chars at the start and end of the string? Or cases like when the string is only whitespace? Or all `-`s? If not, just use `'/^[a-z,.\s-]+$/i'`.

Comment: Or do you need to make sure non-whitespace chars only appear at the start/end of the string? Try `'/^[a-zA-Z.,-]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z.,-])*$/'`

Comment: I need to make sure non-whitespace and chars in start and end. And both of your pattern is work, thankyou somuch :)
I want to ask you something, if it not bother you :)

Comment: Yeah, just drop a comment below my answer.

Comment: My question has been answered by your answer below :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to make sure non-whitespace characters only appear at the start/end of the string, use

```
'/^[a-zA-Z.,-]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z.,-]+)*$/'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dNC4s2/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z.,-]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters, `.`, `,`, `-`
- `(?:\s[a-zA-Z.,-]+)*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `\s` - a whitespace
  - `[a-zA-Z.,-]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters, `.`, `,`, `-`
- `$` - end of string (or `\z` to match the very end of the string)

If you do not want to restrict the chars at the start and end of the string, just use

```
'/^[a-z,.\s-]+$/i'
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-z,.\s-]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters, `.`, `,`, `-` or whitespace chars
- `$` - end of string (or `\z` to match the very end of the string)

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dNC4s2/2).

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 ['position','match', 'pattern' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z., ]+$/;', 'message' => 'Job Position can only contain Alphabet and Spaces only'],
```